# $\mathbb{R}(x)$ as non o-minimal structure

Tags: model-theory, rational-functions, ordered-fields

Let us consider the field of real rational functions in one variable $\mathbb{R}(x)$ as an ordered field with $ x > r$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$.  have to show that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is not o-minimal. I imagine that it is meant that the language of the structure is $ \lbrace 0, 1, \cdot, +,-,  < \rbrace $, but the text of the exercise is not explicit on this.

Comment: The text does say that you're considering it as an ordered field, and the language of ordered fields is indeed that.

Comment: The following is a good first step: can you think of a formula $\varphi$ which in $\mathbb{R}(x)$ holds on all reals but fails on $x$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am tempted to say " $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$", but we do not have a "$\in \mathbb{N}$ " predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the formula $\exists y\, y^2 = z$. Does this formula define a finite union of points and intervals in $\mathbb{R}(x)$? (Note that every positive real number is a square, but $x$ is not.)

More generally, *no* ordered field in which a positive element fails to be a square can be o-minimal. It's a theorem that every o-minimal field is real closed. Real closed ordered fields can be characterized by the properties that every positive element is a square and every odd-degree polynomial has a root.